# SQL - Multiple clauses on JOIN?

Tags: sql

Let me post my database structures first.
Table: monsterdata - http://prntscr.com/92eet
Table: user_team - http://prntscr.com/92eef

I want data in user_team(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6) to be matched with monsterdata.id so that I can retrieve other info. What I managed to do was retrieve only one data

```
    SELECT * FROM monsterdata LEFT JOIN user_team ON monsterdata.id=user_team.m1
```

But what I really want to do is, to include m2,m3,m4,m5,m6 to monsterdata.id=user_team.X

This might be silly but I'm more silly not to figure how to do this.
**Thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 8):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM monsterdata LEFT JOIN user_team 
    ON monsterdata.id=user_team.m1 AND/OR 
    monsterdata.id=user_team.m2 AND/OR ...
```

There you go!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM monsterdata 
LEFT JOIN user_team 
ON (monsterdata.id=user_team.m1
OR monsterdata.id=user_team.m2
OR monsterdata.id=user_team.m3
OR monsterdata.id=user_team.m4
OR monsterdata.id=user_team.m5
OR monsterdata.id=user_team.m6)
```

Comment: Hi @Jonas, what if let's say one (user_team.m1) is null? Will the query return data or discard the row? If it were an AND then it would have discarded. But since it is an OR then it will not discard as long as atleast one of them is not null. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition:

```
SELECT * FROM monsterdata 
LEFT JOIN user_team 
ON monsterdata.id = COALESCE(
    user_team.m1,user_team.m2,user_team.m3,
    user_team.m4,user_team.m5,user_team.m6)
```